# Trigger button click when focused textbox and click enter button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 2 textboxes and 2 buttons. These buttons and textboxes linked each other *(first textbox-first button/second textbox-second button)* . If user write something in textbox1 and press enter, enter will be activate button1. If user focused textbox2 and press enter, enter will be activate button2. I tried something but it doesn't work.

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtYonSif.ClientID%>').addEventListener("keyup", function (evente) {
        evente.preventDefault();
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            document.getElementById('<%=btnPanelYonetici.ClientID%>').click();
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('<%=txtKulSif.ClientID%>').addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            document.getElementById('<%=btnPanelKullanici.ClientID%>').click();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using jQuery, you can use element.dispatchEvent().
If you can use jQuery, use trigger() function.

Using dispatchEvent in javascript

```
var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});

var myButton = document.getElementById('button_id');
myButton.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Using trigger in jQuery.

```
$("#button_id").trigger('click');
```

Comment: I am not using jQuery and dispatchEvent not working on my project.